# Typed DataSet vs Linq to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, strongly-typed-dataset

I am new to LINQ.I used Strongly Typed DatSet. What is lacking in Typed DataSet to go for 
LINQ to SQL?

Comment: you can look at this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081916/difference-between-linq-to-sql-linq-typed-datasets-ado-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this blog post:

[Aaron's Technology Musings: LINQ to SQL != Typed DataSet Replacement](http://blog.magenic.com/blogs/aarone/archive/2007/08/27/LINQ-to-SQL-_21003D00_-Typed-DataSet-Replacement.aspx)

Pay close attention at the end of the article, describing the **potentially** two different use cases where LINQ to SQL or Typed DataSets might come in handy.

Comment: Dead link, but [it's on Wayback Machine](http://goo.gl/wFL3vP).  (I had to use a URL shortener because StackOverflow chokes on the full one.)

Answer (score 1):

Aaron's Technology Musings link is broken; a good alternative source for information comparing use of Linq to typed datasets is on

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386944.aspx

Hope this helps.