# Table does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable, dataset

I need to manage many tables from different databases in my project, both directly from it, both dinalically created and shown in UI (e.g. in DGVs) for be read, filtered and printed. In a previous question it has suggested to me to use DataSets and LINQ, so I've searched and followed examples for add by code a DataSet:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openConnections(); // open connections for SqlCommands I'm using in this piece of code

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlCommand command;
    command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [database1].[dbo].[articles]", connectionSQLDatabase1);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    adapter.Fill(ds, "articles"); //articles becomes the Tables[0] in the ds DataSet

    SqlCommand command2;
    command2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [database2].[dbo].[articles_Details]", connectionSQLDatabase2);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter2.SelectCommand = command2;
    adapter2.Fill(ds, "articles_Details"); //articles becomes the Tables[1] in the ds DataSet

    // LINQ code to query ds DataSet (.....)
}
```

Now at this point of the code I need to query my ds DataSet, I've seen I can do it with LINQ, but almost all examples of LINQ I've seen are structured in a way that I don't think matches with my code.

I was expecting to write LINQ code like (example from the web):

```
var query = from person in people
                 join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner
                 select new { OwnerName = person.FirstName, PetName = pet.Name };
```

but I can't write the tables names this way without getting error:

> table does not exist in the current context.

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong, in the global project I have to do I have to add various tables from different databases in my dataset, then perform INNER, LEFT and RIGTH JOINS and many other data manipulations, it would be very useful to have a direct control on the tables in the code like this last example seems to give. Adding this DataSet to my project I've correctly followed an example, it is correct, cause debugging the content of my ds I get the entire content of my tables.

Hope someone could help.

Comment: First read this: LinQ vs Linq2SQL https://stackoverflow.com/a/1081932/6560478

Comment: Ok, maybe I get the problem. Now I'm tring to add new data sources to my project via the Visual Studio procedure. I go `code` Project ->Add new data source->Database->Dataset`\code`
Here I see the combo labeled "Specify the data connection used by the application for connecting to the database", but it contains only 3 references to connectionstrings relative to 3 out of the 6 database I have. If I go with the button "New connection", it opens the "Add connection" form, but searching the other database it doesn't find anything.
Should I manage some parameter for get all my db showed in there?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since I was asking for an INNER JOIN way via LINQ in my case and I've found a solution, I post it hoping could be helpful for someone:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{ 
    openConnections(); // open connections for SqlCommands I'm using in this piece of code

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlCommand command;
    command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [database1].[dbo].[articles]", connectionSQLDatabase1);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    adapter.Fill(ds, "articles"); //articles becomes the Tables[0] in the ds DataSet

    SqlCommand command2;
    command2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [database2].[dbo].[articles_Details]", connectionSQLDatabase2);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter2.SelectCommand = command2;
    adapter2.Fill(ds, "articles_Details"); //articles becomes the Tables[1] in the ds DataSet


// LINQ code to query ds DataSet:

var query = from artic in ds.Tables["articles"].AsEnumerable()
            join artic_det in ds.Tables["articles_Details"].AsEnumerable()
            on artic.Field<int>("id_art") equals artic_det.Field<int>("id_art")

            select new
            {
                id_art_in_articles = artic.Field<int>("articles"),
                descr_article = artic.Field.Field<string>("description"),
                id_art_in_articles_Details = artic_det.Field<int>("articles_Details")
            };


     closeConnections(); // close connections for SqlCommands I'm using in this piece of code        

}
```

Then putting out on the console every record, I could verify that this is effectively an INNER JOIN among the two tables.